# Generate a voltage that is 7 volts below the input voltage for at least 250 mA in the range of 20-26 volts

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

For programming bipolar ROMs I need a programming voltage of U=27V,30V,33V and an input voltage of U-7V. My first idea was to use a Zener diode in series to drop 7V at the diode. However, the needed current of at least 230 mA is too high for usual Zener diodes.

Is there a simple way to get the 2nd voltage with a transistor?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa1Mmw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Might it also work with a negative voltage regulator like the 7905, with a zener somehow to generate -7V with respect to the U rail and then use this negative voltage but with respect to the real ground?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdmxkr.png)</sup>

Comment: In the 2nd picture, it is of course not 1V but just U

Comment: That's easy http://tinyurl.com/ya2wpyag

Comment: Which bipolar ROMs? What voltage tolerance is allowed?

Comment: @BruceAbbott MMI 6301, 256x4 bit, the LSI bipolar data book does say nothing about a tolerance except the range must be 20V to 26V. First try 20V three times, if it didnt blow the fuse, try 23V tree times, and at last 26 volts three times... So since I only have 5 of these chips and two must be programmed correctly I would say 26V is the upper limit without tolerance...

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks!

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G49wJ.png  http://tinyurl.com/y8gcmk3f

Comment: MMI bipolr PROM programmer http://www.classiccmp.org/cini/aim65/MMI-535.pdf

Comment: According to the [datasheet](https://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/6791074502167909808), Vout is supposed to be applied 10us after Vpp. So apparently you are meant to use separately switched supplies, not both together. However the minimum delay time is 0us so it might be OK.

Comment: This is only for voltage generation. I would use another transistor to switch on the voltage and also I have to put in a parallel capacitor to account for the allowed signal rise time of the voltage. As I understand it, if the current rises too fast, it might also destroy neighbouring bit fuses inside the ROM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this, though the accuracy might not be good enough.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDBZ6v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1 dissipates about 7V * 256mA = 1.8W so it needs a bit of a heat sink.